# Space in batch script

Tags: batch-file, whitespace

I'm trying to create a batch-File that passes parameters with spaces.

```
::create mono PCX file
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.06\bin\gswin64.exe" -q -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=%3 -r200 -g1728x2285 -sDEVICE=pcxmono -sOutputFile="%~dpn2._temp_.%%d.pcx" "%1" -c quit

::create zip file
7za a "%2" "%~dpn2._temp_.*.pcx"
```

My issue is that if %1="test case.zip" I only get test.zip. Is there any way to make the Windows cmd.exe interpreter passing the parameter with spaces correctly in %2?

Best.
wishi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes are a state machine - the 1st quote turns quoting on, the 2nd off, the 3rd on, etc.

Your problem is the quotes around `"%1"`.

You pass in `"test case.zip"` on the command line, so `%1` = `"test case.zip"`, and the added quotes results in `""test case.zip""`. Your parameter is no longer quoted properly, so the parser sees 2 parameters:

1. `""test`
2. `case.zip""`

All you need to do is remove the quotes in your code: `"%1"` --> `%1`

Another option is to use the `~` modifier to remove any existing enclosing quotes before you add your own: `"%~1"`. The `~` modifier has no effect if the parameter is not enclosed in quotes.